# Adding characters automatically to searchBar textField while user is typing?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am wondering if there is a way to add characters automatically to a searchBar textField while the user is typing. For example, if the user typed 533 then I want to automatically add " X " to it. I tried to do the following:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty == false {
        if searchText.count > 2 {
            searchText.insert(" X ", at: 3)
        }
    }
```

However, Xcode is displaying an error message next to searchText.insert(" X ", at: 3) stating:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'searchText' is a let constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the value of `searchText`. Method parameters are constants. Create a local variable with the new value. Then update the search bar's text.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.count > 2 {
        var newText = searchText
        newText.insert(" X ", at: 3)
        searchBar.text = newText
    }
}
```

But this still has issues that you need to work out. This doesn't account for the user moving the caret or the fact that you will add an X far too many times as the user enters more text into the search field.

Comment: Thanks a lot @maddy this sorted out my issue.